# Gremlin/Tinkerpop - is there a way to add metadata to a union step so I know which query the resulting traversal came from?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune

This is a little strange, but I have a situation where it'd be beneficial for me to know which traversal an element came from.

For a simple example, something like this:

```
.union(
   select('parent').out('contains'),   //traversal 1
   select('parent2').out('contains')   //traversal 2
)
.dedup()
.project('id','traversal')
.by(id())
.by( //any way to determine which traversal it came from? or if it was in both? )
```

Edit: One thing I found is that I can use Map with Group/By to get partly there:

```
.union(
   select('parent').out('contains')
   .map(group().by(identity()).by(constant('t1'))),  
   select('parent2').out('contains')   
   .map(group().by(identity()).by(constant('t2'))), 
)
.dedup() //Dedup isn't gonna work here because each hashmap will be different.
.project('id','traversal')
.by( //here I can't figure out how to read a value from the hashmap inline )
```

The above query without the project/by piece returns this:

```
[{v[199272505353083909]: 't1'}, {v[199272515180338177]: 't2'}]
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach might be to just `fold` the results. If you get back an empty list you will know you did not find any on that "branch":

```java
g.V('44').
  union(out('route').fold().as('a').project('res','branch').by().by(constant('b1')),
        out('none').fold().as('b').project('res','branch').by().by(constant('b2')))
```

which yields

```java
{'res': [v[8], v[13], v[20], v[31]], 'branch': 'b1'}
{'res': [], 'branch': 'b2'}
```

UPDATED after discussion in comments to include an alternative approach that uses nested `union` steps to avoid the `project` step inside the union. I still think I prefer the `project` approach unless the performance when measured is not good.

```java
g.V('44').
  union(local(union(out('route').fold(),constant('b1')).fold()),
        local(union(out('none').fold(),constant('b2')).fold()))
```

which yields

```
[[v[8], v[13], v[20], v[31]], 'b1']
[[], 'b2']
```

Comment: Thanks Kelvin.  I was hoping to do the projections after the union because they're relatively complex and computationally expensive.   I was hoping to dedup the results before doing any further projections because there could be overlap between the 2 traversals.  I know this is a bit convoluted but unfortunately that's the issue I'm trying to solve.  I appreciate your help as always.   Ideally I could do something like that group().by() query and then later dedup based on the traversal, but read t1 or t2.  As far as I can tell there's no way to read the value of the hashset inline.

Comment: I should add that the reason I'm doing this at all is because I'm trying to avoid a very expensive computation later in the projection, and I can skip it altogether if I knew which union'd traversal each vertex came from.

Comment: I think you will either need to just use `as` labels and handle empty lists later, or al least produce some kind of collection from each branch of the `union`.

Comment: Another option is nested `union` steps which avoids the `project` up front but may still not be the most efficient query. I'll add an example to the answer.